# How to Edit Recipient Number Notification in Phone which is sent by Shopify?

Tags: shopify

I have set My shop Number +123456789 but the customer receive notification from anther Number.
Now I want to change receipt Number

[image]

Comment: I think you need to add a valid phone number, otherwise, the system default is used.

Comment: The SMS notifications are sent from a number Shopify can control, it's impossible for them to use your own number, that would be a huge security risk

Comment: You can maybe get a dedicated number (not used by anyone else) with a paid option, but that's the best you can hope for. You will never have your own number used as the sender.